# Get start and end date of a week. Month, week number, and year is given as user input

Tags: objective-c

My code should bring the date of a particular week, when the user provide the month, week number, and year. For example: If my user input is month (String) --> "October", week (Int) -- > 1, year (int) --> 2019, the above input should give the response like startDate --> 01/10/2019, endDate --> 07/10/2019.

If the user give the last week of any month it should bring the remaining days in the month. Week calculated from Sunday.

My attempted code giving start date and end date for current month / current

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

cal.firstWeekday = 1;// set first week day to Monday
// 1: Sunday, 2: Monday, ..., 7:Saturday

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfTheWeek;
NSDate *endOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear
       startDate:&startOfTheWeek
        interval:&interval
         forDate:now];
//startOfTheWeek holds the beginning of the week

endOfWeek = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval - 1];
// endOfWeek now holds the last second of the last week day

[cal rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
       startDate:&endOfWeek
        interval:NULL
         forDate:endOfWeek];
// endOfWeek now holds the beginning of the last week day

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

NSLog(@"start: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:startOfTheWeek]);
NSLog(@"end:   %@", [formatter stringFromDate:endOfWeek]);
```

Comment: i have tried but i have got the start date and end date for current month

Comment: So for example for November first week 2019 it should return startDate 1/11/2019 and endDate 4/11/2019 or should it be sunday 3/11/2019?

Comment: No it should be 1/11/2019 and endDate 4/11/2019.

Comment: And for last week or October and November should be what...

Comment: for the last week it should return the dates which belong to the month alone, For example take September 2019 last week has only two days so if the user inout last week it should return the two dates only which is 29/9/2019, 30/9/2019

Comment: Check the anwer, hope it does what you wanted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this that fulfills your criteria I think

```
NSInteger year = 2019;
NSInteger month = 11;
NSInteger week = 1;

NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

cal.firstWeekday = 2;

NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.calendar = cal;
comps.year = year;
comps.month = month;
comps.weekday = cal.firstWeekday;
comps.weekdayOrdinal = week - 1;

NSDateComponents *startOfTheMonthComps = [NSDateComponents new];
startOfTheMonthComps.year = year;
startOfTheMonthComps.month = month;
NSDateComponents *endOfTheMonthComps = [NSDateComponents new];
endOfTheMonthComps.year = year;
endOfTheMonthComps.month = month + 1;

NSDate *startOfTheMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:startOfTheMonthComps];
NSDate *endOfTheMonth = [[cal dateFromComponents:endOfTheMonthComps] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];

NSDate *date = [comps date];
NSDate *startOfTheWeek;
NSDate *endOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear
       startDate:&startOfTheWeek
        interval:&interval
         forDate:date];

endOfWeek = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];

startOfTheWeek = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];


if ([startOfTheWeek compare:startOfTheMonth] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    startOfTheWeek = startOfTheMonth;
}

if ([endOfTheMonth compare:endOfWeek] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    endOfWeek = endOfTheMonth;
}
NSLog(@"start %@", startOfTheWeek);
NSLog(@"end %@", endOfWeek);
```

So for 1st week of November you get `Fri Nov  1` and `Mon Nov  4` and for last week of September - week 6 `Sun Sep 29` and `Mon Sep 30`